# Is there a Windows equivalent to Mac OS X's document proxy icons?

Tags: windows-7, document-management

In Mac OS X, all document based applications will show the filename and icon in the document's title bar. From this icon you can drag and drop it to other applications such as attaching it to an email, move or copy it to another location, or if you hold down command and click, it will show the path to the document.

Is there an equivalent in Windows (7)?, built in, or via system extension.

Currently if I'm working on a document and I want to attach it to a reply email, I find the easiest method is to 'Save As' and then drag and drop from the File Dialog to my email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the program.  Word has an email option in the File tab. Same with Excel and Access.

Dragging and dropping works.  I just copy the file path and paste it when Outlook asks for the attachment.

Comment: Apologies for being dense, but where can I get the file path from?  Also, the Email option in Office programs is modal, so you can't interact with Word/Excel, or with Outlook while the new Email message is open. You also can't use it to reply to an email, it's only good for sending new emails.

Comment: You can get the filepath a few ways. When you save, you can copy the filepath along the top of the Save dialog. Shift+RightClicking the file also gives you the option of copying the FullPath of the file. Also, take advantage of the Libraries and Favorites.  Pinning a temporary location to the favorites, like Sharepoint Sites will save you a ton of time.  You can drag them on and drag them off. It is surprising how few people use the Favorites group.